# django HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed in html form

Tags: python, django, http

I am new to Django and I've been trying to develop a simple site that asks the user for their email address and height. It then saves it in the database and sends an email to the user and redirects them to a page saying that it was successful.

Now the problem is whenever I press 'Submit', I get a HTTP 405 method not allowed error.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    #url(r'^success/$', views.SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
]
```

# forms.py
    class HeightForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
    class Meta:
        model = Height
        fields = ['email', 'height']
```

```
# views.py
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    form_class = HeightForm
    template_name = 'heights/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Height.objects.all()

class HeightFormView(View):
    form_class = HeightForm
    template_name = 'heights/success.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = form_class(None)

    def post(self, request):
        print('a' * 1000)
        form = form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid:
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            height = form.cleaned_data['height']

            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(template_name)

    #render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

```
# index.html
{% extends 'heights/base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Collecting Heights</h1>
    <h3>Please fill the entries to get population statistics on height</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required="true"/><br />
        <input type="number" min="50" max="300" name="height" placeholder="Enter your height in cm" required="true" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>

    <a href="#">Click to view all heights in database</a>
{% endblock body %}
```

The code doesn't even get to the `print('a' * 1000)` line without generating an error. Chrome just goes to a `This page isn't working` page and displays `HTTP ERROR 405`.

I have Googled this error, but haven't found anthing helpful. Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: where is ur route in `urls.py` ? where is the path in `action` of your form?

Comment: @Prakash Palnati updated code to add `urls.py`. And I'm not sure what to put in the `action=""` for the form. Should it be `{% url 'heights:success' %}` or something like that?

Comment: add a route for your form to get submitted in urls.py and use the same in action. should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a route for your form to get submitted in urls.py and use the same in action. should work fine.

`urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        url(r'^saveForm/$', views.HeightFormView.as_view(), name='form'),
    ]`

And in your html form,

```
<form action="/saveForm" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have any URL defined for the HeightFormView. The form is rendered by the IndexView and posts back to itself; that view does not allow a POST method.

You would need to define a URL for HeightFormView and refer to it in the action via the `{% url %}` tag.